# Is there a way to switch the fields calculated using a slicer (or a pull down menu) in a excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a some data about an insurance product. The dataset contain information including policyno start year, time of records, premium, claim amount, claim number and etc.

The dataset looks like pretty much like this:

```
startyear  time   premium  claim_amount  claim_no  
2019      2019Q1  100        20            5   
2019      2019Q2  150        10            2  
2019      2019Q3  140        12            2  
2019      2019Q4  135        15            4  
2019      2020Q1  110        17            3    
2020      2020Q1  160        30            8
```

I can use pivot table to calculate two measures (percent of claim amounts to premiums and avarage claim amounts) for policies starting from a specific year and track the changes of these two measures over the time.
The pivot table will look like this:

```
average claim amount  time|startyear   
         2019     2020  
2019Q1  20/5      #DIV  
2019Q2  30/7      #DIV  
2019Q3  42/9      #DIV  
2019Q4  57/13     #DIV  
2020Q1  74/16     30/8
```

or

```
percent of claim  
time|startyear   
         2019     2020  
2019Q1  20/100    #DIV  
2019Q2  30/250    #DIV  
2019Q3  42/390    #DIV  
2019Q4  57/525    #DIV  
2020Q1  74/635    30/160
```

Now instead of dragging caculated fields, I wonder if I can create a pull down menu or use slicer to change the measures presented in my pivot table.

Comment: You can't use a slicer to change from average to percent if that is what you are asking

Comment: Thank you for replying. I figure out that I can use VBA to achieve this.